# git.properties file is not generated automatically after every commit with git-commit-id-plugin

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

This is the configuration that I have for the git-commit-id-plugin

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${git.commit.id.describe-short}</finalName>
 <plugins>
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.19.1</version>
           <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}\www\Tests</testSourceDirectory>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
          </configuration>
     </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
                 <executions>
                    <execution> 
                      <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}\.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}\git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

In eclipse when I clean the project the file git.properties is correctly created at /target/classes/. However I'm expecting that after every git commit maven recompiles and creates the file again so that the git properties file will be updated with the new commit properties, but this is not happening it keeps the last ones that were generated when I cleaned the project.

Thanks in advance.